# Access Queries doesn't get all the required records

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've imported a table from Microsoft excel and when i use query to get the required range of records using **Between** function, when i enter 1 and 20 the records with the value 2-9 aren't returned, or 10 and 200 11-99 aren't returned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely because the data type of the column is defined as Text. When you have a text value access uses a text based order to lookup for the values. What you need to do is to convert the value to number, like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2
from Table1
WHERE Val(col1) BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

But the better solution will be to fix you table structure so that the numeric values are stored in the numeric data types